# Getting the coordinates of the button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get the coordinates of the button when I click on the button in `tkinter`. How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The `winfo_*` methods will give you information about a window. For example, `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` will return the screen (not window) coordinate of the upper left corner of the widget. `winfo_x` and `winfo_y` will return the coordinate of the widget relative to its parent. You can get the width and height with `winfo_width` and `winfo_height`.

Answer (score 0):

try this small example.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text=str(1))
btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.update()

widget_x, widget_y = btn.winfo_rootx(), btn.winfo_rooty()
print(f'{widget_x}, {widget_y}')

root.mainloop()
```